# Replace NA when last and next non-NA values are equal

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a sample table with *some* but not all `NA` values that need to be replaced.

```
> dat
   id message index
1   1    <NA>     1
2   1     foo     2
3   1     foo     3
4   1    <NA>     4
5   1     foo     5
6   1    <NA>     6
7   2    <NA>     1
8   2     baz     2
9   2    <NA>     3
10  2     baz     4
11  2     baz     5
12  2     baz     6
13  3     bar     1
14  3    <NA>     2
15  3    <NA>     3
16  3     bar     4
17  3    <NA>     5
18  3     bar     6
19  3    <NA>     7
20  3     qux     8
```

My objective is to replace the `NA` values that are surrounded by the *same* "message" using the first appearance of the message (the least `index` value) and the last appearance of the message (using the max `index` value) **by id**

Sometimes, the NA sequences are only of length 1, other times they can be very long.  Regardless, all of the `NA`'s that are "sandwiched" in between the same value of "message" before and after the `NA` should be filled in.

The output for the above incomplete table would be:

```
 > output
   id message index
1   1    <NA>     1
2   1     foo     2
3   1     foo     3
4   1     foo     4
5   1     foo     5
6   1    <NA>     6
7   2    <NA>     1
8   2     baz     2
9   2     baz     3
10  2     baz     4
11  2     baz     5
12  2     baz     6
13  3     bar     1
14  3     bar     2
15  3     bar     3
16  3     bar     4
17  3     bar     5
18  3     bar     6
19  3    <NA>     7
20  3     qux     8
```

Any guidance using `data.table` or `dplyr` here would be helpful as I'm not even sure where to begin.

As far as I could get was subsetting by unique messages but this method does not take into account `id`:

```
#get distinct messages
messages = unique(dat$message)

#remove NA
messages = messages[!is.na(messages)]

#subset dat for each message
for (i in 1:length(messages)) {print(dat[dat$message == messages[i],]) }
```

the data:

```
 dput(dat)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), message = c(NA, "foo", "foo", NA, "foo", 
NA, NA, "baz", NA, "baz", "baz", "baz", "bar", NA, NA, "bar", 
NA, "bar", NA, "qux"), index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by doing it by id? i.e. if in this data, row 6 had "foo" and so did row 8, row 7 would nevertheless not be filled but left missing? I don't think this is currently illustrated in your data example

Comment: That is correct, 7 would be left messing in that case since the `id` of row 6 is 1 and the `id` of row 8 is 2.  And if row 7 were "foo", row 6 would still remain NA, again because of differing ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform an `na.locf0` both fowards and backwards and if they are the same then use the common value; otherwise, use NA.  The grouping is done with `ave`.

```
library(zoo)

filler <- function(x) {
  forward <- na.locf0(x)
  backward <- na.locf0(x, fromLast = TRUE)
  ifelse(forward == backward, forward, NA)
}
transform(dat, message = ave(message, id, FUN = filler))
```

giving:

```
   id message index
1   1    <NA>     1
2   1     foo     2
3   1     foo     3
4   1     foo     4
5   1     foo     5
6   1    <NA>     6
7   2    <NA>     1
8   2     baz     2
9   2     baz     3
10  2     baz     4
11  2     baz     5
12  2     baz     6
13  3     bar     1
14  3     bar     2
15  3     bar     3
16  3     bar     4
17  3     bar     5
18  3     bar     6
19  3    <NA>     7
20  3     qux     8
```

Answer (score 1):

An option that uses `na.approx` from `zoo`.

First, we extract the unique elements from column `message` that are not `NA` and find there positions in `dat$message`

```
x <- unique(na.omit(dat$message))
(y <- match(dat$message, x))
# [1] NA  1  1 NA  1 NA NA  2 NA  2  2  2  3 NA NA  3 NA  3 NA  4

library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
out <- do.call(coalesce, 
               lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) as.double(na.approx(match(y, i) * i, na.rm = FALSE))))
dat$new <- x[out]
dat
#    id message index  new
#1   1    <NA>     1 <NA>
#2   1     foo     2  foo
#3   1     foo     3  foo
#4   1    <NA>     4  foo
#5   1     foo     5  foo
#6   1    <NA>     6 <NA>
#7   2    <NA>     1 <NA>
#8   2     baz     2  baz
#9   2    <NA>     3  baz
#10  2     baz     4  baz
#11  2     baz     5  baz
#12  2     baz     6  baz
#13  3     bar     1  bar
#14  3    <NA>     2  bar
#15  3    <NA>     3  bar
#16  3     bar     4  bar
#17  3    <NA>     5  bar
#18  3     bar     6  bar
#19  3    <NA>     7 <NA>
#20  3     qux     8  qux
```

---

**tl;dr**

When we call

```
match(y, 1) * 1
# [1] NA  1  1 NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

we get the elements only where there are `1`s in `y`. Accordingly, when we do

```
match(y, 2) * 2
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2 NA  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

the result is the same for the `2`s.

Think of `1` and `2` as of the first and second elements in

```
x
# [1] "foo" "baz" "bar" "qux"
```

that is `"foo"` and `"baz"`.

Now for each `match(y, i) * i` we can call `na.approx` from `zoo` to fill the `NA`s that are in between (`i` will become `seq_along(x)` later).

```
na.approx(match(y, 2) * 2, na.rm = FALSE)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

We do the same for each element in `seq_along(x)`, that is `1:4` using `lapply`. The result is a list

```
lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) as.double(na.approx(match(y, i) * i, na.rm = FALSE)))
#[[1]]
# [1] NA  1  1  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#
#[[2]]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  2  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#
#[[3]]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3  3  3  3  3  3 NA NA
#
#[[4]]
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4
```

(`as.double` was needed here because else `coalesce` would complain that *"Argument 4 must be type double, not integer"*)

We are almost there. What we need to do next is to find the first non-missing value at each position, this is where `coalesce` from `dplyr` comes into play and the result is

```
out <- do.call(coalesce, 
               lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) as.integer(na.approx(match(y, i) * i, na.rm = FALSE))))
out
# [1] NA  1  1  1  1 NA NA  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3 NA  4
```

We  can use this vector to extract the desired values from `x` as

```
x[out]
# [1] NA    "foo" "foo" "foo" "foo" NA    NA    "baz" "baz" "baz" "baz" "baz" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" "bar" NA    "qux"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach without grouping to fill the values and then replace back with `NA` if they were filled incorrectly.

`tidyr::fill` by default fills missing values with the previous value, so it will overfill some values. Unfortunately it doesn't respect grouping so we have to use an `if_else` condition to fix its errors.

First, we capture the original missing value locations and calculate the max and min `index` for each `id` and `message`. After filling, we join on these `index` boundaries. If there is not a match, then the `id` changed; if there is a match either it was a correct replacement or the `index` is outside the boundaries. So we check in the locations with original missing values for these conditions and replace back with `NA` if they are met.

EDIT: this can be broken on other input, attempting to fix

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), message = c(NA, "foo", "foo", NA, "foo", NA, NA, "baz", NA, "baz", "baz", "baz", "bar", NA, NA, "bar", NA, "bar", NA, "qux"), index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")

indices <- dat %>%
  group_by(id, message) %>%
  summarise(min = min(index), max = max(index)) %>%
  drop_na

dat %>%
  mutate(orig_na = is.na(message)) %>%
  fill(message) %>%
  left_join(indices, by = c("id", "message")) %>% 
  mutate(
    message = if_else(
      condition = orig_na &
        (index < min | index > max | is.na(min)),
      true = NA_character_,
      false = message
    )
  )
#>    id message index orig_na min max
#> 1   1    <NA>     1    TRUE  NA  NA
#> 2   1     foo     2   FALSE   2   5
#> 3   1     foo     3   FALSE   2   5
#> 4   1     foo     4    TRUE   2   5
#> 5   1     foo     5   FALSE   2   5
#> 6   1    <NA>     6    TRUE   2   5
#> 7   2    <NA>     1    TRUE  NA  NA
#> 8   2     baz     2   FALSE   2   6
#> 9   2     baz     3    TRUE   2   6
#> 10  2     baz     4   FALSE   2   6
#> 11  2     baz     5   FALSE   2   6
#> 12  2     baz     6   FALSE   2   6
#> 13  3     bar     1   FALSE   1   6
#> 14  3     bar     2    TRUE   1   6
#> 15  3     bar     3    TRUE   1   6
#> 16  3     bar     4   FALSE   1   6
#> 17  3     bar     5    TRUE   1   6
#> 18  3     bar     6   FALSE   1   6
#> 19  3    <NA>     7    TRUE   1   6
#> 20  3     qux     8   FALSE   8   8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: on what input  can it be broken?

Comment: My previous approach I think would fail if there was a missing value isn row 8, it would have replaced row 8 but left row 7 as `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Another tidyverse solution using case_when. Edited to avoid filling after end of series.

```
library(dplyr)

dfr <- data.frame(
  index =  c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  message = c(NA, "foo", "foo", NA, "foo", NA, NA, "baz", NA, "baz", "baz", "baz", "bar", NA, NA, "bar", NA, "bar", NA, "qux"),
  id =  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
)

dfrFilled <- dfr %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(
    endSeries = max( # identify end of series
      index[message == na.omit(message)[1]],
      na.rm = T
      ),
    filledValues = case_when(
      min(index) == index ~ message,
      max(index) == index ~ message,
      index < endSeries ~ na.omit(message)[1], # fill if index is before end of series.
      TRUE ~ message
    )
  )
```

Comment: yes `output$message[19]` should remain NA because the `bar` message sequence has ended at `output$message[18]`

Comment: Probably too late, but updated solution provided in edit. Good luck! Many other nice solutions provided here.

Answer (score 0):

If you fill both ways and check for equality that should work, as long as you account for grouping and index:

### tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  arrange(id, index) %>%
  mutate(msg_down = fill(group_by(., id), message, .direction = 'down')$message,
         msg_up   = fill(group_by(., id), message, .direction = 'up')$message,
         message = case_when(!is.na(message) ~ message,
                             msg_down == msg_up ~ msg_down,
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  select(-msg_down, -msg_up)

   id message index
1   1    <NA>     1
2   1     foo     2
3   1     foo     3
4   1     foo     4
5   1     foo     5
6   1    <NA>     6
7   2    <NA>     1
8   2     baz     2
9   2     baz     3
10  2     baz     4
11  2     baz     5
12  2     baz     6
13  3     bar     1
14  3     bar     2
15  3     bar     3
16  3     bar     4
17  3     bar     5
18  3     bar     6
19  3    <NA>     7
20  3     qux     8
```

### data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

setDT(dat)[order(index),
           message := ifelse(na.locf(message, na.rm = FALSE) == na.locf(message, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE),
                             na.locf(message, na.rm = FALSE),
                             NA),
           by = "id"][]

    id message index
 1:  1    <NA>     1
 2:  1     foo     2
 3:  1     foo     3
 4:  1     foo     4
 5:  1     foo     5
 6:  1    <NA>     6
 7:  2    <NA>     1
 8:  2     baz     2
 9:  2     baz     3
10:  2     baz     4
11:  2     baz     5
12:  2     baz     6
13:  3     bar     1
14:  3     bar     2
15:  3     bar     3
16:  3     bar     4
17:  3     bar     5
18:  3     bar     6
19:  3    <NA>     7
20:  3     qux     8
```