# Replace NA conditionally in a more efficient way

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a series of IDs interspersed with `NA`:

```
x <- c("A", NA, NA, "A", "B", NA, "B", "A", NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", NA, "A")
```

I need to replace any `NA` by the last non-`NA` value **if** the next non-`NA` value is **identical** with the last non-`NA` value (e.g., `"B", NA, "B"`). However, the number of `NA` between two identical non-`NA` may vary. Which brings to me to this bulky code:

```
library(dplyr) 
ifelse(is.na(x) & lag(is.na(x),1) & lag(is.na(x),2), lag(x,3),
       ifelse(is.na(x) & lag(is.na(x),1),lag(x,2),
              ifelse(is.na(x) & lead(x,1) == lag(x,1) |
                       is.na(x) & lead(is.na(x),1), lag(x,1), x)))
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" NA  "A"
```

- it does the trick but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient method that caters not only for predetermined numbers of intervening `NA`but allows for *any* number of intervening `NA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `zoo` could be:

```
ifelse(na.locf0(x) != rev(na.locf0(rev(x))), NA_character_, na.locf0(x))

 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" NA  "A"
```

Comment: Instead of the double `rev` you can use `na.locf0(x, fromLast = TRUE)` as shown in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54718756/1851712) by the author of `zoo` (included among the links above). Cheers

Comment: @Henrik I totally forgot that it has that parameter. Thanks!